# java EE project encountered NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, ejb-3.1, wildfly-10

I am working on a Java EE project with

1. jdk 1.8
2. wildfly 10.1.0 final
3. intellij idea 2016.3

The project has a web application module and an ejb module, and the structure is as follows:
[image: project structure]

And the two modules have already been deployed successfully
[image]

But when I tried to call the session bean, the ejb project went wrong and threw an error

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONArray`

I use JSON in class `DAOHelperImpl` in the ejb module, and I've already add the dependency. I tried to put the jar in various packages such as /ejb/lib or /web/web/lib, but none of them are working.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Move the jars libraries from `/web/web/lib` into

> /web/web/**WEB-INF**/lib

By Convention the general folder for auto included jars is:
web-project-name/webContent/WEB-INF/lib

Read more here: https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/web_inf_lib_jar_meta

*I am not aware how IntelliJ handles Java EE projects.

In Eclipse the EAR and WAR are in separate projects and can be assigned to each other.*

Comment: I've tried your advice but still got the same error.

Comment: I can hardly figure out why the EJB project shall have dependency put in the lib of the web project.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is raised due to my bad understanding of how this web application together with the ejb module works: I deploy the web module and the ejb module separately, and it seems that wildfly can only link to the lib of the web module.
The solution is to deploy only the web application to the server and add the ejb module to the web application.